# Is it normal to get overleveled weapons from chests?

Tags: borderlands-2

Sometimes while playing Borderlands, I find a big red chest and then realize that the weapons are like +2 or +3 higher level than I am.  I can't even play with those items until I level up.

Is it normal that the loots are uber-leveled like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is normal for items above your level to drop when you are playing in a zone higher than your level (maybe you went straight through all the Story Missions without exploring and doing side missions, for example), or in co-op mode where the host is at a mission level (and therefore zone) higher than your level.

Enemy and item levels are based on the zone in Borderlands 2, kind of like most MMORPGs.

Comment: Note: Scaling changes some during subsequent playthroughs. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86395/1134 for more details on level scaling.