# Playthrough 2 (TVHM) re-scaling?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do subsequent playthroughs work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work)

I finished Playthrough 1 at Level 37. Then I (accidentally) went into Playthrough 2 (True Vault Hunter Mode) and barely progressed beyond a few minutes of wandering around. I believe Palythrough 2 would then scale to the same Level 37.

Then I went back to Playthrough 1 and killed the Warrior a number of times for loot and then went to the Pirate DLC. Say after I finished all these, I am at Level 41 and then I go into Playthrough 2 (again) for all the missions proper.

- Will Playthrough 2 re-scale to my Level 41?
- If not, will the subsequent missions catch up with my Level 41?

It is pretty boring already and not challenging with the Pirate DLC at Level 30 and not scaling to my Level 37.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

No They are not going to scale with your level.. the enemy level is dependent on area (map)
but don't worry because in later maps of TVHM you will find enemies up to level 52.

If you feel its boring then Kill **Terramorphus the invincible** & **Vermivorus the invincible** :D. I think its impossible if you don't have bee shield.

Comment: "Bee shield" ?  What's that ?

Comment: @Anto Its a booster kind of shield dropped by hunter hellquist  (orange drop). Best part of this shield is that it doesnt take away your shield with booster shot so you can keep firing booster shots. For terra I used conference call(shotgun) with lvl 60 bee shield(+50k Dmg). lets calculate per shot damage (6X3X(50000 + 5000)) = 990000 Damage pershot, It take 3-4 mags to finish him off.

Comment: Ok, it sounds crazy (and scary) :D

Comment: oops its level 50 bee shield

Comment: Yeah, I farmed Hunter for the Bee for more than 2 hours before getting one at Lvl 29 and then another at Lvl 30. I was like Lvl 36. But good enough for me to kill Warrior without Conference Call.

Comment: The DLC scale was capped at Lvl 30 for me. :(  I think quite a few would be above that at PT1 if the side quests were completed (and some farming), not to mention those already at TVHM when the DLC was released.

Comment: @wujoo Killing warrior is easy I am talking about Terrramorphus the invincible and vermivorus the invincible :D vermi gives a class mod having 6 skills with +5