# Has the level cap been raised to 61?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have seen an [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/112628/38416) which states that the level cap has been raised to 61. Is this correct?

Comment: There is a links in my answer there, which clearly states that the level cap is raised to 61, I don't know why you have to ask if that is true here.... close voting.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, [here is the official Borderlands 2 website page where it says the cap is raised](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1022/borderlands-2-level-increase-and-other-changes)

Comment: To be fair to the original poster, that question isn't specifically about the level cap being raised, although I too was confused as to why he assumed you might be wrong about that.

Comment: I think a better phrasing of this question would be "Under what circumstances is the level cap raised to 61"?  Having been away from the game for a while, the fact that the DLC is required would not have been obvious to me.  Even still, I think it is just a rephrase of the other question, so I'm going to vote to close as Duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The level cap has been raised to 61 provided that you purchase the [Ultimate Vault Hunter's Upgrade Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/224200/).  The level cap will not increase until and unless you do this.