# How to complete Borderlands 2 missions in right order?

Tags: borderlands-2

I already completed Borderlands 2 on normal mode many month's ago. But without any DLC. Now I have all released 4 DLC and my version is 1.7.0. I want start play again from level 1. But I'm completely confusing how to play. Can you tell me like below:

1. Complete all main & optimal missions in normal mode.
2. Teleport to "name here" for "name here" DLC, and complete it.
3. Teleport to "name here" for "name here" DLC, and complete it.
4. Teleport to "name here" for "name here" DLC, and complete it.
5. Teleport to "name here" for "name here" DLC, and complete it.
6. Change difficult mode to "mode here".
7. Repeat again.

I don't know which DLC requires what level. I don't know how to reach those DLC zones. I don't know which DLC should I play first and which one later.

edit: wtf is that playthrough 1, playthrough 2, playthrough 2.5 things?

Comment: And for your second question - which you should (if at all) post *separately*: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work?rq=1

Comment: My English is not so good. I cant completely understand URL you provided. I need more clear flow information like I requested.

Comment: You've got multiple questions here, mostly answered by the answers in those two links. What specifically is unclear?