# Can you join a game, beat the final boss and have scaling?

Tags: borderlands-2

I saw this message in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10825726#10825726)

> hi - any borderlands2 players here? I'm in TVHM now and finished two DLCs there so i'm lvl 47 with almost no story missions done. unfortunately those don't scale so i wonder if it'll be possible to **join a multiplayer game with someone who's almost done with TVHM story and kill The Warrior to unlock scaling and then continue doing the story missions**

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86395/42984) seems to verify that beating playthrough 2 begins that scaling of enemies and such.

> beating playthrough 2 scales enemies and rewards to your level

Could scaling be enabled by joining a multiplayer game on Playthrough 2 and just beating the final boss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. TVHM Scaling is unlocked by beating the story mission line in TVHM; merely being present for the final boss's death will not count.

At best, it might give him the option to skip the last quest when he comes to it, but even that would require him to be in-game for most of the other player running the actual quest, including at least turning it in.

Comment: Essentially what I had meant.

Comment: So joining a multiplayer game with someone having the final story mission won't automatically add it to my quest list, too?

Comment: @ThiefMaster It will add it to your list for that specific game, but it will not permanently add it no.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, not unless you yourself have *just* unlocked it by beating the previous mission, no. And not even then for story missions, since those autostart when the previous one finishes.

Comment: So is there any point a player could jump in towards the end of the game for this to happen (i.e. last 2 or 3 story missions)?

Comment: @Batophobia Not really, short of playing the whole campaign you cannot short circuit the save to allow you to unlock scaling, although you could edit the save if you HAVE to have scaling.