# level 53 in borderlands 2 after 2.5 playthrough

Tags: borderlands-2

So I finished the 2.5 playthrough and I'm only on level 53. I am having difficulty getting more xp without being able to replay missions again. Any ideas for how to still get xp?

Comment: I think you can restart a playthrough. That way you just play the game again. And there is iirc various DLC that gives higher level enemies.

Comment: Hi @ids thanks for your comment. I don't know how to start the next playthrough. I have bought ultimate vault hunter dlc upgrade packs 1 and 2. Can you perhaps help me?

Comment: Well, I have never finished the 2.5 playthrough, I hoped you could somehow reset it. But not sure. Sorry, can't help you. My highest level char is only 39 :)

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work?rq=1 this question should help. It says you can reset your playthrough after beating the 2.5 one. Somewhere in the main menu. (No clue where sadly).

Comment: I know you can restart playthrough 3 (UHVM).  I don't believe you can reset any other playthrough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that point I would progress to Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode (UHVM, or playthrough 3).  The DLC that unlocks levels 51-61 also gives you access to UHVM.

If you really want to stay in 2.5, I would suggest farming for some useful equipment or killing BNK3R.  BNK3R has a long initial run, but if you save & exit there, you start right in the area and it takes ~15 sec to get him to spawn.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I don't know how to start the ultimate vault hunter playthrough. I have bought ultimate vault hunter dlc upgrade packs 1 and 2. Can you perhaps help me?

Comment: It's the same way you choose between normal and TVHM.  Blanking on how exactly to do this, I'll edit answer if I have more details.

Comment: Go to "Select Character", choose a character that's finished at least the first mode, and the "Select Playthrough Mode" window will pop up.