# What is the True Vault Hunter Mode?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

After I killed the final boss of of the Pre-Sequel a message popped up that said that I have unlocked the "True Vault Hunter Mode". It also said that the enemies are tougher, the loot better and that you can level up even further.

Now while this provides some information It doesn't really cover all of it (or at least thats how I feel). I started playing this new mode and I noticed that somehow the enemies react different to elemental damage etc and Deadlift (the first real boss) is a lot harder to kill.

What exactly are the differences between the normal playthrough and the True Vault Hunter Mode?

Comment: The same as the TVHM and UVHM of Borderlands 1 & 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do subsequent playthroughs work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work)

Comment: I had major issues with undeadlift aswell. But I leveled up some more and then done it without a problem. I was 25 at the time, while he was 30. And when I was 30 I had no problem with him.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Well I'm not sure if they really are the same. That's why I'm asking. I'm talking about **Pre Sequel** here.

Comment: @Jutschge: Oh, I think a better title would be "Is TVHM of the Pre Sequel different from the same mode in Borderland 1 or 2?" : )

Comment: Unless the difficulty increase is the same (i.e. some regular enemies have armor now) I think this is a separate question because it's a different game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference that you will notice is the inclusion of Tiny Tina into Athena's narration of the story. The enemies will of course be scaled up based on the area that you are playing in (scaled to your level in UVHM) and some will have shields or armour now. The loot will be of higher quality but RNG is RNG, i have found the easiest way to get a legendary you want is just by farming the sentinel or Iwajira for a slightly higher chance of a legendary that you don't want, then hitting the grinder. on the quest side of things the jumps in levels between the quest are a fair bit steeper than in BL2 and you will need to do side quests or farming bosses instead of simply relying on quests alone to level up. When it says level up higher, it means you will level up faster than in the first play through as you can level up past the recommended level (if you enjoy killing enemies for a measly 1xp. That is about it for TVHM.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, in TVHM you get way better loot and you will find tougher enemies. Additionally, some enemies have other names.
But theoretically, almost all the missions (side and main) will be the same as in normal vault hunter mode.
If you beat the true vault hunter mode, you will unlock the ultimate vault hunter mode.