# How do I get enemies to scale (Borderlands 2)

Tags: borderlands-2

OK so I'm going through play through 2 and I'm trying to farm for an Unkempt Harold, but Savage Lee is level 35 and I'm level 46 now. How do I get him to scale to level so I can farm for Unkempt harold on my level. At the starting of the game as in like Three Horns Divide all the enemies are under leveled, I just want to know how to get the back to my level so I can farm Savage Lee again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do subsequent playthroughs work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's quite a duplicate, though it may have the answer. If I remember right, once you progress through an area, the enemies stay the level you were when you first went through the area.

Comment: Until you get to Ultimate Vault Hunter mode, enemies have a level cap. In Ultimate, enemies scale to your level (often a bit higher). Farming is pretty useless prior to Ultimate.

Comment: You should definitely try finishing TVHM first. Enemies will scale up once you're done with the playthrough. Up to around 50 so then you can farm your gear for UVHM.

Comment: @Longspeak That sounds like an answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Gimme a sec...

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Finish the Playthrough, then farm.

As discussed in [this much more comprehensive answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work/86395#86395), in Normal and True Vault Hunter Mode, Enemies have a predetermined level cap per area during the story play, and do not scale with your level. However, after you kill the warrior in True Vault Hunter Mode, every area will reset to level 50. Then you can farm for level 50 gear. If you have the DLC to level past 50, you'll level while farming. Be careful you don't level so much the weapon becomes obsolete by the time you get it.

Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode is the only mode where enemies should scale to your level... often to a level or two above your level.

Comment: +1, looks good. You could even reference this [longer, existing answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86395/108003) to a similar question for more authority.

Comment: To be honest, I was expecting the question to get closed as a dupe because of that other answer, which was why I didn't answer in the first place. But then you said my comment should be an answer. :p

Comment: We're experimenting with closing less questions as dupes at the moment. The other answer has information that can answer this one, but the actual question isn't the same, and the scope is a little different. I think we're moving towards answering the actual question asked, and just linking the similar answer for additional information. Not sure how it's going to shake out just yet.

Comment: kewl. already edited my answer to reference that other.