# Can I reach level 72 without True and Ultimate Vault hunter Mode?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am playing this game solo.

I think I am going to get a lot of exp from the DLC quests in Normal. So I can reach level 72.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 8):

***No***, you cannot reach level 72 without True or Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode. On a normal playthrough, your level is capped at 50.

You will not be able to get higher than level 50 until you attempt playthroughs 2 or 3. Your second playthrough (New Game+, essentially) will raise your level cap by 11, to 61. Your third playthrough (New Game++) will raise your level cap by another 11, to a maximum level of 72.

Thus, without playing True or Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode, you cannot get above level 50.

See [this Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work) for more detailed info about how subsequent playthroughs work.

Comment: Even if I had the level upgrade DLC?

Comment: Correct. You'll still need to do multiple playthroughs to get above level 50.

Comment: @Lyeco Also, it's worth noting that enemies cap each playthrough as well. Iirc, things won't be higher than mid-30s until you start an NG+

Comment: Yeah, the original playthrough caps your level at 50, but your loot is capped much lower, IIRC, around level 30 to 40. If you grind to level 50 and then go to TVHM (New Game+) you'll be facing level 50 enemies with level 30-40 loot. You'll get rolled *hard*. Source: I did this on accident before I knew TVHM existed. It took me a ton of luck to get past the Gluttonous Thresher.

Answer (score -5):

is true after level 50 your advance will be slowed down drastically if you will not start UVHM but once you start it you can level up very quick just only farming savage lee idk, Gentle in the dust for Lyuda so is not necessary to complete UVHM for levelling to 72 but only to start it and your levelling speed will back to normal . start UVHM doing first missions and level up quickly farming ,then you good to go in Digistruct peack without UVHM finished , doing the UVHM story line at which OP you want for updating your gear with the proper OP level rewards

Comment: The existing answers to this and other questions seem very much like this is not true. If it is, please show sources. And definitely work on your grammar.

Comment: Hi Fabian I’m not here to help the ppl with the grammar , my apologies, about what I said now , all is very true and connected with the question cause , probably that user needed the level 72 for starting the OP , and can you please tell me what is not true ? after you finish TVHM but you don’t want to start UVHM you are kinda stacked at 50 , then once you start UVHM the levelling speed is back to normal , as well , for DP the only requirement is to be on lv72 , so please tell me what is not true . Thank you

Comment: I'm just saying that you're claiming the opposite of the existing answer by a 50K user with 6 upvotes showing sources. So please show your own sources so that it can be objectively checked if you are correct.

Comment: I don’t get you , I am not supporting any user in here , I just said that it is possible to level up quicker even if you skip a part of the UVHM , but for sure he had to do the first two playgrounds , then he will leave the last one for later which looks like a good thing in order to level quicker to 72

Comment: And sorry but that user with 6 upvotes did a mistake saying that you can’t reach 72 without completing TVHM and UVHM  which is not true as all you need is only to start UVHM

Comment: Show your sources! Where did you get that info from?

Comment: Hey my sources are my Krieg which levelled to 72 just starting the UVHM , leaving the rewards of the main story or optional stories for later when he will be maybe OP 7 and he will do the fire of cult of followers later having the shield/ reward at OP 7 level , and if you think I’m wrong then you show the sources as you accuse , just read the requirements for OP Aand you will see that is only one main : to reach the level 72 . Thank you

Comment: I don't know what that is except that it's the German word for "war". Please provide a link.

Comment: The opposing site already linked to their sources, just look at the other answer.

Comment: Ok go to Digistruct Peak description you can find it everywhere and read the description plus requirements , is simple you can do it

Comment: The question was if he had to _start_ UVHM to reach level 72.  Your grammar is confusing and it's not clear what you're saying/suggesting.  It's very unclear if you're saying they need to start UVHM or not.

Comment: No, "it's simple" is not the criterion. If you don't want your answer to be downvoted and possibly deleted, make it complete yourself instead of instructing the reader to search for an answer themselves. Just look at other answers (with upvotes) on this site and you'll see what is considered a good answer. Or read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Listen he asked if he can reach 72 without True and Ultinate not what you say .. and I answered Yes you can reach 72 without doing 90%  of Ultimate , just farming and levelling quickly then he can OP then go back to finish the Ultimate when he wants

Comment: @Dan He asked if he could do it **without** True and Ultimate Vault Hunter modes.  Even according to the information you mention; the answer should be **no**.  He is required to enter Ultimate Vault hunter mode to raise the cap to level 72.  No one mentioned anything about _finishing_ them.  This answer seems confusing at best because you seem to be addressing a different question than was asked.

Comment: Ok let’s put it like that , -90% of UVHM is not literally “WITHOUT” but it meant to be a help , actuality is helping a bit

Comment: @Dan If you're trying to say this answer helps; I disagree.  The lack of grammar makes it very unclear what you are trying to say.  The part of what you say that actually _answers_ the question, is already covered by the other answer.  The rest seems to be advice that isn't what was asked.

Comment: but despite my bad grammar it seems you got the idea very clear so let’s forget about universtary grammar high level lessons , in my opinion my answer helped that person to make his life easier if he really wants to reach 72 without completing the UVHM obviously for OP levels . I do apologise for my grammar and I full stop here . Thank you